# Issue when combining Impromptu and Ideal tme out plug in

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

As per my requirement i am working with custom alerts, after a research i found these two as per my need

For ideal time out

http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/a-new-and-improved-jquery-idle-timeout-plugin/

For Pop up

http://www.clientsideasp.net/2009/06/16/showing-beautiful-message-boxes-in-aspnet-web-forms-using-jquery-impromptu/#comment-209

Combining these two my design is as follows

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default5.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default5" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <link href="impromptu/impromptu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="impromptu/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="impromptu/jquery-impromptu.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Timer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="idletimeout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font: 12px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        }
        #content
        {
            padding: 10px;
        }
        a
        {
            color: #477099;
        }

        #bar
        {
            background: #252823;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            border-bottom: 4px solid #C3D3DA;
        }
        #bar h1
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 40px;
            letter-spacing: -1px;
            text-shadow: 0 0 4px #000000;
        }
        #bar h1 span
        {
            color: #C3D3DA;
        }
        #bar div
        {
            float: right;
            margin-top: -50px;
            padding: 20px 20px 0 0;
        }
        #bar a
        {
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        #bar div a:hover
        {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    </style>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function confirmSubmit() {
            var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            var flag = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
                    if (inputs[i].checked) {
                        flag = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (flag == 0) {
                $.prompt('Select One?'
            , {
                buttons: { Ok: true }
            }
                );
            }
            else {
                $.prompt('Are you sure you want to submit?'
            , {
                buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false }
                , callback: confirmSubmitResult
            }
        );
            }
            return false;
        }

        function confirmSubmitResult(v, m, f) {
            if (v) //post back if the user clicked OK
                $('#<%= btnSubmit.ClientID %>').click();
        }    
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close
        {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // setup the dialog
        $("#demo").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 400,
            height: 200,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: {
                'Yes, Keep Working': function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                'No, Logoff': function () {
                    // fire whatever the configured onTimeout callback is.
                    // using .call(this) keeps the default behavior of "this" being the warning
                    // element (the dialog in this case) inside the callback.
                    $.idleTimeout.options.onTimeout.call(this);
                }
            }
        });

        // cache a reference to the countdown element so we don't have to query the DOM for it on each ping.
        var $countdown = $("#dialog-countdown");

        // start the idle timer plugin
        $.idleTimeout('#demo', 'div.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:first', {
            idleAfter: 5,
            pollingInterval: 2,
            keepAliveURL: 'keepalive.php',
            serverResponseEquals: 'OK',
            onTimeout: function () {
                window.location = "Handler.ashx";
            },
            onIdle: function () {
                $(this).dialog("open");
            },
            onCountdown: function (counter) {
                $countdown.html(counter); // update the counter
            }
        });



    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div id="demo" style="display: none;" title="Your session is about to expire!">
            <p>
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
                You will be logged off in <span id="dialog-countdown" style="font-weight: bold">
                </span>seconds.
            </p>
            <p>
                Do you want to continue your session?</p>
        </div>
        <h1>
            Keep Idle for 5 Seconds</h1>
        Name:
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" Text="Check" />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Check" />
        <!-- The button which will display the delete confirmation -->
        <input type="button" onclick="return confirmSubmit();" value="Submit" />
        <!-- Hidden command button that actually issues the delete -->
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Style="display: none;" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
        <!-- Explanation -->
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But the alerts are not getting displayed as per my requirement. Can any one help me..

Error when clicking button

[image]

Comment: do you get any javascript error ? this is like asking us to debug your copy/paste code...

Comment: I am not getting any error. I am not asking to debug i just post what I wrote

Comment: The -1 is because you do not even see that you load the same and the same again and again, means that you do not actually work with your code but you rather make a question for others works on. Also you need to learn the javascript error console.

Answer (score 2):

For start remove the many jQuery loads. I see you load the jQuery on 3 points !!!, remove the two...

line 58

```
<script src="impromptu/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Line 104

```
 <script src="impromptu/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Line 135

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then add all load scripts on top. You also load the same css of jQuery ui. Please make this correction and see if then work or not to focus on some real issue. Also check the javscript error console, for sure you get tens of errors all ready.

When you copy/paste code, at least take a look of it.

Comment: If i remove this `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>` then ideal time out is not getting displayed. If i have that alerts are not working

Comment: @Chaitanya and remove the line 104, and open the javascript error console !

Comment: I did that and posted the image what my error console is having

Comment: @Chaitanya Move all javscript file to load on top of the page, this is because it did not find this function.

Comment: even then i am not getting the alerts required. As per said i made all at the top as follows

Comment: @Chaitanya the $prompt is part of Impromptu, do you load this file after the jQuery but before the fist call ? can you update your code with the new one to see it ?